# what does this java program do

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I cant figure out what does this java program do. It gives 31 and 12. Thanks in advance ! Regards

```
int x = 911; 
int y= 29;           
int z = 0;                        

if (x>=0) {                       
    if (y>=1) {                   
        while (y<=x) {            
            x = x - y;            
            z = z + 1;               
        }   
        System.out.println(z);
        System.out.println(x);                                         
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your guess? Go step-by-step and you will recognize that process as something that you already know

Comment: Hint: what different operators can you put between 911 and 29?

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. I recomend doing a dry run or using a debugger. Thats the place to start and would be helpful in the long run

Comment: How many times does `29` go into `911`? And, what is the *remainder*?

Comment: the statement if (x>=0)  is  basically "if 911 is bigger or equals to zero". if that statement is true then go to next statement.

Comment: So if I write x/y and x%y and print it out, that's basically the same ?

Comment: Thanks to all ! Regards

Answer (score 3):

This is common if-else and while statement. which you can use in any language but the result is same. It will go into the both if statement every time and while statement until the expression condition satisfied. Here in your code z is a a counter which count how many times it will go to the while loop and it will go 32 times. After 32 times while loop expression is not satisfied and never go to this loop again.

- You can check it your self by just putting those print statement into while loop block.It will print how many times it will go to this block and what will be the value of your variable.

Comment: I understand what if statement does and I understood what this particular does. But still can't understand why is this so written instead of x/y , x%y and does the same thing. Thanks for the answer anyways !